# Turning a vertical category menu into a dropdown on mobiles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To turn a vertical category into a drop down hamburger list in Bootstrap. Do I need to just change the Bootstrap classes, or do I need to then create the HTML/CSS of what the drop down would be underneath?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Categories</div>
<div class="panel-body"><ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"><li><a   href="http://example.com/index.php?cPath=1">Category #1</a></li><li><a href="http://example.com//index.php?cPath=2">Category #2</a></li><li><a href="http://example.com//index.php?cPath=3">Category #3</a></li><li><a href="http://example.com/index.php?cPath=21">Category #4</a></li></ul></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some examples to how to do this for vertical categories:

```
http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-hamburger-drop-down-menu-with-css-and-jquery/
```

And here an example of an hamburger menu for horizontal categories:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav scroll-nav" id="sortableMenuItems">
                <li>
                    <a  href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="#">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is what you can do for the vertical one:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Categories</div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                        <li><a   href="http://example.com/index.php?cPath=1">Category #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com//index.php?cPath=2">Category #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com//index.php?cPath=3">Category #3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/index.php?cPath=21">Category #4</a></li>      
                    </ul>


                </div><!--navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>

        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has this built in already though, just need to edit the classes?

Comment: I have added your vertical menu to my previous answer. Try it.